# Relative paths when using import and endfloat packages

Tags: import, endfloat

I am combining multiple tex files (different papers) that are from different projects. I decided to use the `import` package. Figures and tables of each file should go at the end of a chapter. Because of that, I need to use the `endfloat` package as well.

Nonetheless, when I try to compile the file generated by the `endfloat` does not assign the correct path for figures and tables. The `endfloat` does not use the path I assign for the `import` package.

Thought how to solve it?

For figures, it seems I can partially solve it with `graphpath`. I have no idea how to solve it for tables.

```latex
%%%%%%%%%%%%
% file 1 - location: ~root/paper1/tex/manuscript.tex
% manuscript.tex
blah blah blah
\begin{table}
\input{../tables/table1.tex}
\end{table}
%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%
% table 1 - location: ~root/paper1/tables/tables1.tex
% table.tex
\begin{tabular}
\end{tabular}
%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Main tex file
% location: ~root/
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{endfloat}
\begin{document}
\chapter{title}
\import{paper1/tex/}{manuscript.tex}
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

> File `../tables/table1.tex' not found. \input{../tables/table1.tex}

Answer (score 0):

I would do yourself a favour and avoid using sub files this way.

My dad used to tell me "My sons father is my fathers son" 
I tell my daughter "My daughters father is my Mothers son"

You have nothing at all wrong with the mwe files they work perfectly loading any table in that location. However what IS that location?

So why would I get a message such as

> File `../tables/table1.tex' not found. \input{../tables/table1.tex}

there is only one reason i.e. you have not given us the correct relative location of table1.tex which you store in

```
~root/paper1/tables/table1.tex
```

If I change `\input{../tables/table1.tex}` to

```
\input{paper1/tables/table1.tex}
```

then your mwe runs without error.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I don't like this structure either. However, I need it to put together different articles in my dissertation. As you mention, we did not get any error when doing my last instructions.  Thanks for catching that. I did some edits in my post to reproduce my error. I think you can reproduce my error now.